# Basic Obj-C question: Calling methods on an object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Background: I'm a .NET guy who has no prior experience in Objective-C/Cocoa, but I'm working through Aaron Hillegass' book, "Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X" trying to pick up the basics. (Great book so far, BTW!) For the purpose of completing one of the optional side challenges, I'm writing a document-based app that lets users draw ovals in arbitrary locations.

I have two classes, interfaces as follows:

```
@interface OvalDrawDocument : NSDocument
{
    IBOutlet OvalView* myOvalView;
}
@end

@interface OvalView : NSView {
    NSMutableArray *ovals;
}
@property (readwrite, assign) NSMutableArray *ovals;
@end
```

In the implementation of `OvalDrawDocument` I'm trying to use the auto-generated property accessor for `ovals` like so:

```
// in OvalView.m
@synthesize ovals;

// in OvalDrawDocument.m
[myOvalView setOvals:loadedOvals];                // setter?
NSMutableArray *ovalsToSave = [myOvalView ovals]; // getter?
```

However, the compiler warns me that the methods aren't found, and they don't work at runtime either. They appear in Code Sense, but I guess that doesn't really mean anything (Still getting used to the differences between XCode/VS here) I'm guessing there's some Obj-C concept I'm not quite grasping here, possibly related to the fact that `myOvalView` is also an `IBOutlet`, but I'm pretty lost. What should I be doing, **and more importantly, why?**

---

**Update**: I didn't declare OvalView.h in OvalDrawDocument.m. Doing so fixed the compilation warnings. However, saving and loading still don't seem to work and I can't figure out why.

As requested, I've posted the full source code online for perusal: [Browse](http://www.control-v.net/stackoverflow/867035/OvalDrawer/) or [Download (59KB zip)](http://www.control-v.net/stackoverflow/867035/OvalDrawer.zip).

Comment: Is the @synthesize ovals within @implementation OvalView block?

Comment: You should post the whole files so we can see where the problem is. Most likely you have something in the wrong place, not imported or not declared, but its hard to tell from what you posted.

IBOutlets/IBActions have no affect on your code, they are stripped out when you compile. Xcode makes the proper connections and gets rid of them.

Comment: Just to point out, you probably want retain rather than assign when dealing with objects and properties.

Comment: StefanB: Yes, the @synthesize is within the @implementation. Martin: I'm using garbage collection so retain and assign are supposed to do the same thing, but good point regardless.

Answer (score 5):

The warning: Import OvalView's header in the OvalDrawDocumentation implementation file.

The messages not working at runtime: Make sure you have actually connected the outlet in IB.

Also, as Martin Pilkington said in his comment on your question, you probably should declare that property with `retain`, not `assign`.

Comment: If the calls don't work at runtime, then that can't be the (only) problem.

Comment: Importing the header fixed the warnings. The outlet is properly connected in IB to the best of my knowledge -- I'll post the full source to be sure.

Comment: Yes, the outlet is connected, and saving and loading appear to mostly work. Two problems you do have are: 1. You've not declared any real type information in Info.plist, so the file saves with extension “????”; 2. Probably for the same reason, the Dock does not recognize that I can drop that file onto your app to open it. Also, you're not adding undo actions to the document's undo manager. This causes two more problems: 1. I can't undo (obviously). 2. The change count doesn't get updated, so the dirty dot doesn't appear in the close box.

Comment: The reason why you don't see the ovals in the oval view is that nib loading happens *after* document loading (after all, which one's more likely to fail?). More conceptually, your document (which is primarily a controller) is expecting the view to hold onto its model for it, but that's the controller's job. Move the ovals array to the document class. It's OK to let the view have a copy, but primary responsibility for holding the model rests with the controller, which is your document.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the IBOutlet keywrod, which is simply a "helper" keyword for Interface Builder and is defined as "nothing" at compile time. You did import the relevant header files and did an alloc/init on myOvalView?

Comment: Why would you do alloc/init if the view already exists in the nib?

Comment: It may exist in the nib file without having been allocated and initiated, you're looking for [[zzz alloc] initWithNib:@"nib name here"];

Comment: NSView has no initWithNib: method.

Comment: oh sry, I was confusing NSView with NSViewController, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to show more of the code, since you appear to have the right things there, so you must be missing something somewhere else. Also, if you're going to declare ovals as a property, then it would make sense to use the property syntax in OvalDrawDocument:

```
// in OvalDrawDocument.m
myOvalView.ovals = loadedOvals;                // setter
NSMutableArray *ovalsToSave = myOvalView.ovals; // getter
```